# shell script - store output of "kill -HUP 1234" (gunicorn command) to variable and check if the variable contains "No such process"

Tags: django, bash, shell, gunicorn

I tried below command to store output to variable :

```
k=$(kill -HUP 1234)  #command getting executed but not storing to variable
echo "$k"
```

For checking if the output contains the word, i can do like this  :

```
  if [[ outputvar =~ .*No such process*. ]]
```

As per the examples, above should work , but i donno why its not working . Can you tell me correct way so that if I cannot restart the process, I can atleast start a new process with direct gunicorn_django command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually such error messages are output on the `stderr` stream, while the `$()` construct returns only the `stdout` stream. You need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`:

```
k=$(kill -HUP 1234 2>&1)
```

Your regular expression has an error: the `*.` at the end must be `.*`; you will also need to quote your strings in your test:

```
if [[ "$k" =~ .*No\ such\ process.* ]]
```

Note that `"$k"` is quoted, while the spaces in the regular expression are escaped; you cannot quote the regular expression (as `".*No such process.*"`), as using a quoted string in a `=~` test forces string match instead of a regular expression match.

Comment: What about "No such process", as it contains spaces in between, i am getting error